# How to resolve conflicting linker dependencies?

Tags: c, visual-c++, linker, dllexport

If I have two libraries, `A.lib` and `B.lib`, both of which export `foo` and `bar`, how do I tell the linker to use the symbol `foo` from `A.lib` and the symbol `bar` from `B.lib`?

Comment: Are the libraries in question static libs or DLLs?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I've run into all possible combinations (static/static, static/dynamic, dynamic/dynamic), so hopefully there is a solution for all of them. But if there isn't, dynamic/dynamic is the most important/useful for me at the moment.

Comment: Can you recompile the libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.  For your example you can have definitions from `foo.lib` or `bar.lib` but not both (especially if you cannot recompile the libraries and set symbol visibility so that only the symbols you want are exported).  The order you link them against your application will depend on which library's definitions are used (you'll have to use the scientific method, I think the first one linked wins).  Niklas Hansson's answer is a great way to do this dynamically but it seems you don't want to modify the original application, either, to dynamically pick/choose what symbols to take out of the libraries.

If you really wanted to you could mangle the symbol tables with a hex editor so that the symbols you *don't* want exported have different names (hacky, but it would work).  I know on Linux there is a tool called `objcopy` that would let you do this (not sure about Windows).

Comment: I don't think *visibility* has anything to do with it. I think the right term for that is *linkage*, the [ELF format supports four different levels of visibility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472666/3285) but regardless of the level chosen LD will complain if the names conflict.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LIB.EXE /EXTRACT ...` to extract only the object files you want to use, and link those files into your own application.

Or you may use `LIB` to create one new library containing the elements you need:

- First, use `/REMOVE` on `A.LIB` to remove `bar.obj`:
  `LIB.EXE /OUT:ANOBAR.LIB /REMOVE:bar.obj A.LIB`
- Then combine `A.LIB` and `B.LIB`, and make sure to use `ANOBAR.LIB` as the last on the command line to ensure its `foo.obj` is used instead of `B.LIB`'s:
  `LIB.EXE /OUT:COMBINED.LIB B.LIB ANOBAR.LIB`

Details are found here: [Managing a library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e17b885t.aspx), especially the paragraph:

> You can use LIB [...] To replace a library member with a new object, specify the library containing the member object to be replaced and the file name for the new object (or the library that contains it). When an object that has the same name exists in more than one input file, LIB puts the last object specified in the LIB command into the output library. When you replace a library member, be sure to specify the new object or library after the library that contains the old object.

I didn't test the command lines given, but I've used similar ones extensively in the past.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dynamic libraries, you could use [dynamic loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) and pick `foo` from A and `bar` from B when loading.

Comment: How is this relevant to resolving conflicting **linker** dependencies? It's just telling me to avoid introducing link-time dependencies in the first place...

Comment: Well, you rather avoid the conflicting linker dependencies by dynamically loading the specific functions you want from each library.